# opencart 2.0.1.1 - Rewards points are not subtracting when order is placed

Tags: e-commerce, opencart2.x

I have opencart 2.0.1.1 and I am facing a problem that let say a customer of my store has 500 rewards points and it place order for buying products by using 100 rewards points. The order get placed but when the same user again come to place order it still shows 500 rewards points to that customer until the admin of store change the status of that customer's previous order to complete.
I have found this one link having same issue as mine , but the solution he used is not solving my problem. Plus I have not found any solution on opencart forums as well. Any Help?

```
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/3637
```

**UPDATE :**

I guess I need to modify the insert query in this confirm () function in this file `catalog/model/total/reward.php` . I am on it but any help would be appreciated!

```
public function confirm($order_info, $order_total) {
        $this->load->language('total/reward');

        $points = 0;

        $start = strpos($order_total['title'], '(') + 1;
        $end = strrpos($order_total['title'], ')');

        if ($start && $end) {
            $points = substr($order_total['title'], $start, $end - $start);
        }

        if ($points) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "customer_reward SET customer_id = '" . (int)$order_info['customer_id'] . "', order_id = '" . (int)$order_info['order_id'] . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape(sprintf($this->language->get('text_order_id'), (int)$order_info['order_id'])) . "', points = '" . (float)-$points . "', date_added = NOW()");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you need to modify customer library file and change reward point calculation. Also make some scenarios first before implementing. Like add reward points back if order cancelled nd so on.

Comment: @Vidhyut Pandya Sir I have updated my question . I need to the insert query which should insert the used rewards points after placing order so that they get subtracted from total , but they only get subtracted when the order status changed to complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by changing the default order status to ***Processing***.
Before the default order status was ***Pending*** due to which the rewards points were not subtracted. So rewards points only subtracted when order **status is not pending**.
Problem solved!